# How to retrieve particular data from JSON file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read JSON file stored locally in my system using jQuery. I want to get some particular data from that file. Let's suppose the file looks like as below:

```
{"statements":[{"subject":{"uriString":"A","localNameIdx":-1},
"predicate":{"uriString":"B","localNameIdx":-1},
"object":{"uriString":"C"}}
```

This is what has been written by Java program. My question is: How can I retrieve the following data`A, B and C`from this file using jQuery? My code to read JSON file is:

```
var arr = [];
$.getJSON("/Users/docs/sample.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.statements, function(i, val) {
        arr.push(val);
    }
}
```

The code does not retrieve `A, B and C`. Could anyone please help me how to get these elements and store them in an array in jQuery. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you do a console.log(data) in the getJSON callback function?

Comment: my formatting edit seems to have collided with your edit changing the JSON: see [the diff](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19844814/revisions) and please re-apply your edit if necessary

Comment: I will try it now. to be honest, I need these data to visualise them using Arbor. Let me check please

Comment: The data above is definitely invalid.  There's an opening bracket for an array, but no closing one, at least.

Comment: `stored locally in my system` Are you trying to read a file on the computer the browser is on, instead of on the server?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Bare in mind JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is just a JavaScript Object, with a funny coat on. So if you have a JSON string, and Jquery, you can use the parseJSON method to rehydrate the string into to the object is really represents.

Such as...

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: AJAX calls automatically convert valid JSON into an object, so that's not required for this :)

Comment: Yeah, hehe... I didn't fully read the question... I just realised that now. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
$.each(data.statements[0], function(i, v){
    // arr.push(v.uriString);
    console.log(v.uriString); // will print A B C
});
```

But, in this case, your `object` should look like this

```
var data = {
    "statements":[
        {
            "subject":{"uriString":"A","localNameIdx":-1},
            "predicate":{"uriString":"B","localNameIdx":-1},
            "object":{"uriString":"C","localNameIdx":-1}
        }
    ] // <-- mising in your question
}; // <-- mising in your question
```

In your question, I didn't find the closing `]}`, I think it was a typo, check [this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Psy3/)

Answer (score 0):

You're only looping through `data.statements`. This only gives you one item, `data.statements.subject`, which is `{"uriString":"A","localNameIdx":-1}`

It appears you want to get the `uriString` of every item, regardless of how nested that item is. To do this, it'd be easiest to define a recursive function.

```
    function getUriStrings( obj ){
        var results = [];
        for(var key in obj){
            if(key == "uriString"){
                results.push(obj[key]);
            }
            else if(obj[key] != null && typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
                results.push.apply(results, getUriStrings(obj[key]));
            }

        }
        return results;
    }
```

Then your code will just be:

```
    var arr = [];
    $.getJSON("/Users/docs/sample.json", function(data) {
        arr = getUriStrings( data );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. At the moment, I am working on your piece of codes. I have got an error in the line where the foreach is in the codes. Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: Whoops, there needs to be a space between "for" and "each".

Comment: Aaand I looked at your object wrong, didn't see the '[' and ']'. after statements.

Comment: Wait, is that opening '[' supposed to be there?

Comment: Does it work with you? I've tried it with and without space and none of them worked. Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: Whoops, no each, just for, mixing up languages now

Comment: This is the file: {"statements":[{"subject":{"uriString":"A","localNameIdx":-1},"predicate":{"uriString":"B","localNameIdx":-1},"object":{"uriString":"C","localNameIdx":-1}}]}

Comment: One more question, please. I am using the following code in order to see the result: `if(key === "uriString"){
                    results.push(obj[key]);
                    document.write(obj[key]);
                    }` Is that possible to see the expected results? I can't see the outputs that I want.

Comment: use console.log, and open it in your browser's js console.